# UEFI Windows + GPT SSD won't boot without CSM enabled

Tags: windows, uefi, gpt

My system is running Windows in UEFI mode, my NVMe SSD is in GPT mode, and everything seems to be in perfectly good order for a boot without CSM (Compatibility Support Module) enabled. However, this is not the case, as my motherboard's BIOS will freeze as soon as I turn on the computer if CSM is disabled. I have also downgraded the BIOS recently. Can anyone shed some light? I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: GPT and CSM are not compatible with one another.  In order to use GPT CSM must be disabled.

Comment: If your PC won’t boot with CSM disabled, that’s a firmware bug, unrelated to Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound It is impossible that my drive is not GPT, as Windows states it is. Moreover, what most likely happened is that the CSM has an extra compatible mode with a drive that has a GPT policy. I haven't converted from MBR. I installed Windows on a GPT drive.

Comment: If the machine works with CSM enabled , what problem, are you trying to solve. I would agree sounds like a firmware bug